# Laravel MİX compile warning

Tags: css, laravel, npm, sass

Laravel webpack js use for sass file compiler. But I have a warning. There is a typo. How to add "import" for Sass? I will add Google fonts.

I am terminal warning;

```
/resources/sass/views.sass:1:1090: missing '{'
```

Comment: Hi AnAlien, are you trying to import Google Fonts into your project? Can you show us what you are currently doing that is causing the error?

Comment: I couldn't do this using sass, but I fixed this problem by putting a link tag between the head tags. @Damon